# why is a date invalid in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Why is the following expression invalid?

```
var hello = new Date(2010, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

For example, `hello.UTC()` doesn't work.

Comment: UTC appears to be a member of the Date constructor itself, and not a member of Date instances

Comment: question has more to do with how JavaScript do OOP i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var hello = new Date(2010, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(hello.toUTCString());
```

and

```
var hello2 = Date.UTC(2010, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(hello2);
```

These two are actually two different functions that print out different things.

`toUTCString()` - Converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time

where as

`Date.UTC()` - returns the number of milliseconds in a date string since midnight of January 1, 1970, according to universal time.

If you are attempting to calculate the milliseconds in a date string since midnight of 1-1-1970 then you will have to use `Date.UTC();`.  However if you are attempting to get properties, in different forms, of the new Date(2010, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0); then you'll have to use its own constructor methods (`toUTCString()` or `getUTCMilliseconds()` and etc).

UTC appears to be a member of the Date constructor itself, and not a member of Date instances.  So, in order to invoke UTC you have to use `Date.UTC();`  `Date()` converts current time to a string, according to universal time and `Date.UTC()` retrieves and use value that is calculated in milliseconds from 01 January, 1970 00:00:00 Universal Time (UTC).  So, they are like a 'static' functions.

Moreover, in JavaScript whenever you use the `'new'` keyword to create a new object (instantiate), the `this` value of the constructor points to the new Object.  So, hello can have a date of its own as oppose to `Date()` or `Date.UTC()`'s `this` would be pointing to a different scope (global i think) which would do its calculation based on 1-1-1970 00:00:00 or return the time which Date function is invoked.  The Object hello, on the other hand, would have a base date which was instantiated with `new Date(2010, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0)` with its set of constructed methods (`toUTCString();` and etc). The new Date with `this` pointing to the new Object using the passed properties as the base "date" value.

With all these being said, `hello.UTC()` is accessing a function that is not a member of its constructor and thus doesn't work.  This is part of the OOP in JavaScript.  This is all on top of my head and probably a bit fuzzy if you are reading this.  Please correct me if i have errors.

Answer (score 3):

> Because UTC is a static method of
>   Date, you always use it as Date.UTC(),
>   rather than as a method of a Date
>   object you created.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var hello = new Date(2010, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
window.alert( hello.toUTCString() );
```